# Can't Import tables to MySQL

Tags: mysql

while trying to import tables to a database I get the following error:

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'pyrea.#sql-16a4_67' (errno: 121) (Details...)
```

This occurs when I try to import this in the SQL tab:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `guild_wars` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `guild_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `enemy_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `begin` BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `end` BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `frags` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `payment` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `guild_kills` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `enemy_kills` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `guild_id` (`guild_id`),
  KEY `enemy_id` (`enemy_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE `guild_wars`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `guild_wars_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`guild_id`) REFERENCES `guilds` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `guild_wars_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`enemy_id`) REFERENCES `guilds` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `guilds` ADD `balance` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AFTER `motd`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `guild_kills` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `guild_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `war_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `death_id` INT NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE `guild_kills`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `guild_kills_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`war_id`) REFERENCES `guild_wars` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `guild_kills_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`death_id`) REFERENCES `player_deaths` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `guild_kills_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`guild_id`) REFERENCES `guilds` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `killers` ADD `war` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

Anybody knows about this?, Sorry but I'm kinda new in this.

Comment: Don't hide the details, tell us

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180660/mysql-errorno-121

Comment: Show CREATE TABLE guilds, CREATE TABLE player_deaths...

Answer (score 1):

attempt to remove the CONSTRAINT

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `guild_wars` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `guild_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `enemy_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `begin` BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `end` BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `frags` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `payment` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `guild_kills` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `enemy_kills` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `guild_id` (`guild_id`),
  KEY `enemy_id` (`enemy_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `guild_kills` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `guild_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `war_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `death_id` INT NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```