# MYSQL error no 121. Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am getting the error no 121 when running the below script. is anyone have any clue as whats wrong with the script?

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Commitment`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Commitment` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0:Eco Commitment|1:Community Commitment|etc',
  `title` VARCHAR(180) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdById` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT -1,
  `createdAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updatedById` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updatedAt` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT '0:Delete|1:Active|2:Deactive|3:Pending|4:Blocked|5:Suspend|etc',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `idxCreatedById` (`createdById` ASC),
  INDEX `idxUpdatedById` (`updatedById` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fkProductUser1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`createdById`)
  REFERENCES `User` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkProductUser2`
  FOREIGN KEY (`updatedById`)
  REFERENCES `User` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
  COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: You don't use `fkProductUser1` or `fkProductUser2` in other tables as foreign keys, do you? [(Source)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180660/mysql-errorno-121)

Comment: Your error is with `FOREIGN KEY` constraint. Check the datatype and column name of the referencing table

Comment: @ChrisForrence yes thats the issue, fkProductUser1 is used in some other table unfortunately. please post this as answer to accept.

Comment: @Gone its the issue as Chris mentioned, thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error code indicates that those foreign key names are already in use. What I'd do is, to make a key unique *and* memorable, is to use

- Key type (idx, fk, ...)
- Table name
- Local column name
- Referenced column name (or referenced table)

In your case, your foreign keys might be

```
fk_commitment_createdbyid_user_id
fk_commitment_updatedbyid_user_id
```